# How to hide an element and show another when Saturday is selected in jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This is for a flower shop, when a customer fills out the form they have to pick a date (jquery datepicker) and time for delivery (select field). Saturday has different delivery times from sun-fri. I've created two different delivery time fields and would like to keep the Saturday one hidden, unless the customer chooses Saturday on the date picker.

This is what I have so far..

```
$('.mydatepicker').datepicker(function() {
 if ($(day == 6)) {
   $('#delivery_time_normal').hide();
   } else {
   $('#delivery_time_saturday').show();
 }
});
```

Comment: You need to use events that are documented in the datepicker api. Which datepicker are you using...there are numerous ones?

Comment: jQuery UI datepicker: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onSelect` event to capture the user selection on the `datepicker`.
This event also receives the selected date as a `string` which you can parse as a `Date` and get the respective weekday, like so:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#mydatepicker').datepicker( {
        onSelect: function(date) {
            var day = new Date(date).getDay();
            console.log("Selected weekday " + day);

            if (day == 6) {
                 $('#delivery_time_normal').hide();
            } else {
                 $('#delivery_time_saturday').show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <input type="text" id="mydatepicker">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will help you,

```
$('.mydatepicker').datepicker(function() {
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  var day = date.getDay();

if (day == 6) {
   $('#delivery_time_normal').hide();
   } else {
   $('#delivery_time_saturday').show();
 }

}
});
```